# Vim as the default editor

Tags: windows, vim

I'm on Windows XP and I just installed GVim 7.3. How do I make the default editor? How can I make it run using the command prompt
e.g.

```
c:\Windows>gvim boot.ini
```

open this file in gvim.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Add Gvim to your PATH variable

To be able to call Gvim from the command line, you have to add the installation directory of Vim to your `PATH` variable. To do that, right click on **My Computer** on the desktop (or in Explorer) → Properties → **Advanced** Tab → Click on Button **Environment Variables**.

In the Dialog, go to the **User Variables** field and search if there is already a `PATH` variable. If there is a `PATH` Variable, select it, click **Edit** and change it as follows:

```
%PATH%;C:/Program Files/Vim/Vim73
```

(or whatever the installation directory of Gvim is).

If there is no `PATH` variable set, create a new one with the content written above.

Confirm everything with **OK**, then open a *new* command window (important!), navigate to the desired directory and type

```
gvim somefile.txt
```

This should bring up your favourite editor.

---

#### Set Gvim as default editor for a certain file type

Adding Gvim to your `PATH` doesn't make Gvim the default editor for a certain file type. This can be achieved the following way:

- In Explorer, right click on any file and select **Open With → Choose Program**
- in the upcoming window, select **Vi improved - A Text Editor** or browse for **gvim.exe** if the entry is not already there
- select the **Always use the selected program ...** checkbox and click **OK**
- from now on, every time you double-click the file, it will be opened with Gvim

  ---

#### The easiest way

If you install Gvim, be sure to check the **Add to context menu** option. If you did that, you can right click on **any** file in the Windows Explorer and select **Edit with Vim**.

Comment: Note that this is the only way I could get this working in Windows 10 in 2022, as well, since I didn't install GVim through the Windows App Store.  It does change the "type" of the file to "<extension> File" rather than "Text File", though.  I've done this with a few "Text File" types.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the any file you want to open -> select Open or Open With ->check always open with the following editor.

Comment: Simply set environment variables the C:\program files\gvim in PATH folder by right click on My Computer->Advance Settings. You shall be able to gvim system wide

Answer (score 2):

1. After installing vim the "Edit with vim..." menu item appears in the context menu (RMB click on any file to check). Thus you can edit any file (not only text file) with just selecting this menu item
2. Add gvim to the PATH variable and you can run it right as you want:

   ```
   c:\Windows>gvim boot.ini
   ```