# How to start Gvim from Command Prompt?

Tags: vim, windows-7, command-prompt

I tried to start `gvim` using `start` command like this

```
start gvim.exe
```

But it doesn't work for `gvim`,  although it does work for `firefox.exe`. My questions are-

1. How can I start `gvim` from command prompt?
2. Why `start` command doesn't work for `gvim.exe`?
3. Are there any additional parameter that I can use when starting gvim from command prompt?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Completely different, so a separate answer:

Actually, -- I just remembered -- Vim isn't normally added to the path variable, it's run through .bat files in C:\Windows.

From [another answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049316/how-do-you-run-vim-in-windows):

> When you install `gVim`:   Please make sure **`Create .bat files for
>   command line use`** is checked.   It'll create several `.bat` files in
>   `C:\Windows\`:
>
> ```
> C:\>cd %windir%
> C:\WINDOWS>dir /b *.bat
> evim.bat
> gview.bat
> gvim.bat
> gvimdiff.bat
> view.bat
> vim.bat
> vimdiff.bat
> vimtutor.bat
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is because gvim.exe is not in your PATH list.  If you know which directory gvim.exe resides, add this directory to your PATH list.  This can be done by typing the following in an Explorer address bar:

```
Control Panel\System and Security\System
```

Then press `Advanced system setings`, then `Environment Variables`.  The PATH is a list of directories separated by a `;`.

Comment: Thanks. That works. But are there any other way, like giving the path with the command itself. It's not possible to set environment variables for all the programs. Another thing is why `firefox` start directly? It's not in my path. I checked.

Comment: From the command prompt you can type in the full path either with or without using `start`.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing just `gvim` instead of `start gvim.exe`. That works for me. Vim isn't in my path environment variable.