# Problems opening Vim from the command line? (Windows 8)

Tags: vim, windows-8, installation

How do you install Vim such that it runs in the command line?

I saw a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049316/how-do-you-run-vim-in-windows) and it said to make sure that

```
[✓] Create .bat files for command line use
```

was checked.  I did make sure that it was checked, but vim won't open in the command line.  However,

```
gvim
```

will open gvim from the command line, which is a pop-up window.  How do I open Vim so that I can edit files directly from the command line?  I think that I need to edit the PATH, but I don't know what that is or how to edit it.

EDIT: I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402615/vim-as-the-default-editor) and followed the directions, tailored to my system.  Now vimtutor will briefly open the vimtutor for less than a second and close it!  But Vim still doesn't work.  Gvim will open Gvim still.

EDIT: I don't think I was clear when I wrote my post.  Running

```
vim
```

does not open Vim on my computer.  Neither does

```
vim.exe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the bottom right Win8 gesture and go as following: `Settings > PC Info > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Environment Variables.` Under system variables find Path in the list.

Path is just a semicolon separated list of directories. Append `vim.exe` to the list and it's now in your path.

Answer (score 1):

You want to run `vim.exe`, not `gvim.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Path under system variables **`"C:\Program Files\Vim\vim82"`** . Then you are all done.

To Edit Environment Variables:
Click on Start Menu -> Type `Environment Variables` and Press Enter [Supporting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj7GT.png) -> In bottom Right Corner you will find "Environment Variables" [Supporting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocZcU.png) -> Under System Variables Search for `Path` [Supporting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCS1V.png) -> Double Click To Edit -> Click on new and Paste the file address given Above[Supporting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxaa5.png)

Now you're done. Test it just by writing vim in Command Prompt or Windows Terminal.